# I have to files and I need to fill the gaps of file LookupHere based on the dates of file AddValueHere

Tags: python, pandas

I am totally new to python and I have no idea if this is the best way to do it. 
I have two txt files:

LookupHere.txt

```
Date,RPM
07/03/2016 1:00,14.21
07/03/2016 1:10,13.67
07/03/2016 1:20,13.17
07/03/2016 1:30,12.98
07/03/2016 1:40,11.44
```

AddValueHere.txt

```
Date    
07/03/2016 0:00    
07/03/2016 1:00    
07/03/2016 1:10    
07/03/2016 1:20    
07/03/2016 1:30    
07/03/2016 1:40    
07/03/2016 1:50
```

Here it is what I wrote:

```
import pandas

AddValues=pandas.read_csv("C:\\Python\\scripts\\AddValueHere.txt")

LookupHere=pandas.read_csv("C:\\Python\\scripts\\LookupHere.txt")

dfAddValues=pandas.DataFrame(AddValues,columns=['Date'])

dfLookupHere=pandas.DataFrame(LookupHere,columns=[['Date'],['RPM']])

with open("C:\\Python\\scripts\\output.txt",'w') as file:

    for i in dfAddValues['Date']:
        if dfAddValues[i] not in dfLookupHere['Date']:
            dfNew = dfLookupHere.resample('RPM').fillna(NaN)
        else:
           file.write=(dfNew)
```

I need an output.txt file as the following:

```
Date,RPM    
07/03/2016 0:00,NA    
07/03/2016 1:00,14.21    
07/03/2016 1:10,13.67    
07/03/2016 1:20,13.17    
07/03/2016 1:30,12.98    
07/03/2016 1:40,11.44    
07/03/2016 1:50,NA
```

I am getting the error

```
KeyError: '07/03/2016 0:00'
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked!

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas.DataFrame.join()

```
import pandas as pd

add_values = pd.read_csv("C:\\Python\\scripts\\AddValueHere.txt")
lookup_here = pd.read_csv("C:\\Python\\scripts\\LookupHere.txt")

# set date to datetime
add_values['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(add_values['Date'])
lookup_here['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(lookup_here['Date'])

# set date to index
add_values = add_values.set_index('Date')
lookup_here = lookup_here.set_index('Date')

# left join
add_values = add_values.join(lookup_here, how='left')
```